# How to hide custom product description tab based on product attribute value?

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, tabs

I've made global product description tab as well as global attribute with yes/no values. Attribute default settings is set to "no". I want to show this additional tab only for products whose attribute value is set to yes.
How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Just override the attributes.phtml file in your theme like so.

> Vendor/Theme/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/view/attributes.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/**
 * Product additional attributes template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes
 */
?>
<?php
    $_helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output');
    $_product = $block->getProduct();
?>
<?php if ($_additional = $block->getAdditionalData()): ?>
    <?php $canShow = $_additional['/custom_attribute_code/']['value']; ?>
    <?php if($canShow) : ?>
        <div class="additional-attributes-wrapper table-wrapper">
            <table class="data table additional-attributes" id="product-attribute-specs-table">
                <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('More Information') ?></caption>
                <tbody>
                <?php foreach ($_additional as $_data): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                        <td class="col data" data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__($_data['label'])) ?>"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

`<?php $canShow = $_additional['/custom_attribute_code/']['value']; ?>`

Replace '/custom_attribute_code/' with your own.